# Issue submitting data to HubSpot from iOS app

Tags: android, ios, swift, hubspot, hubspot-crm

I have this code in iOS that combines a string of values together to submit to hubpot. Everything submits and creates a contact record record except for the product string. Here is the code I have writtne in swift.

```
let params: [String:String] = [
    "email": self.emailTextField.text ?? "",
    "firstname": self.firstnameTextField.text ?? "",
    "lastname": self.lastnameTextField.text ?? "",
    "company": self.companyTextField.text ?? "",
    "phone": self.phoneNumberTextField.text ?? "",
    "what_best_describes_your_role_": self.roleTextField.text ?? "",
    "what_products_systems_are_you_interested_in_": products.reduce("") { "\($0);\($1.currentTitle!)" },
    "toolbox":"Yes"
]
HubspotProvider().register(params: params, completion: nil)
```

Hubspot states you need to append a semi-colon before each entry to submit a string of values. The "what_products_systems_are_you_interested_in_" does not get added to the contact record. I am unsure what is needed. I cannot seem to find much documentation for this. I am attaching an image to show the error in Hubspot. As for an android reference I am adding the code that works for android. Possibly this will be an indicator between the 2 languages on what I am missing here. Thank you all for your help.

Android code reference below:

"what_products_systems_are_you_interested_in_" to ";"+user.products.joinToString (separator = ";"){ it },

[Hubspot Contact Record Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYkK9.png)

Comment: For all who may or may not need it. i found a solution and it was where the semi-colon was placed.

products.reduce("") { "\($0)\($1.currentTitle!);" },

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution in case anyone wants to know. It's where the semi-colon is. See the code for reference.

```
products.reduce("") { "\($0);\($1.currentTitle!)" },

products.reduce("") { "\($0)\($1.currentTitle!);" },
```